# Invaild use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make an after insert trigger that will add the `bnumber` to the table available with the `rack-id` that has the most open slots. To get this I need to take the total number of slots - the number of instances and if there are no free slots then the insert will fail. Below is what I have came up with so far but I don not know if it is at all correct and right now it throws `1111: Invalid use of Group function`.

```
 BEGIN
    insert into 
    Available
    SELECT new.bnumber,max('y.rack-id')  
    From (select count(*) as 'Available.rack-id'
    from Available inner join Rack
    group by 'Available.rack-id'
    ) y
    where max(y.rack-id) > 0;
    
    END
```

updated non error code but is not inserting anything into the table `Available`

```
insert into Available
SELECT new.bnumber,max('y.rack-id')  
From 
(select count(*) as 'Available.rack-id'
from Available inner join Rack on 'Rack.rack-id' = 'Available.rack-id'
group by 'Available.rack-id'
) y
having max('y.rack-id') > 0;
```

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Bike` (
  `bnumber` int NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bnumber`)
)

CREATE TABLE `Rack` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `num-holds` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `Available` (
  `bnumber` int NOT NULL,
  `rack-id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bnumber`),
  KEY `bnumber_idx` (`rack-id`),
  KEY `bnumber_idx1` (`bnumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `bnumber` FOREIGN KEY (`bnumber`) REFERENCES `Bike` (`bnumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `rack-id` FOREIGN KEY (`rack-id`) REFERENCES `Rack` (`id`)
) 

Bike
bnumber,make,color,year
'1', muller, yellow, 2017
'2', muller, green, 2018
'3', muller, red, 2020

Rack
id,location,num-holds  (num-holds is the number of empty slots)
'0', 'Louisville', '3'
'1', 'Clarksville', '4'

Available
bnumber,rack-id
'1', '0'
'2', '0'
'3', '1'
```

so in this examples when you add a new bike it will be something like `bnumber` 4. It will then get the count of instances of `rack-id` so 2 instances of `rack-id` 0 and 1 instance of `rack-id` 1. Then it will subtract the the instances from the corresponding `num-holds`. so this step would be `rack-id 0 has 3 num-holds - 2 instances = 1 empty slot available`. `rack-id 1 has 4 num-holds - 1 instance = 3 empty slots`, so `bnumber` 4 would be inserted into rack with the `rack-id` 1.

Comment: I don't think you can use `MAX()` (or any group function) in a `WHERE` clause.   I think you need to do `HAVING MAX(\`y\`.\`rack-id\`) > 0`.

Comment: Please provide tables structure, sample data and desired result [mre]

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I have added the tables, sample data, and the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are missing a `ON` clause:

```
from Available 
inner join Rack
```

it will look something like this:

```
ON Available.col = Racl.col
```

Then, in your outer query:

```
insert into Available
SELECT new.bnumber
      ,max('y.rack-id')  
From 
(
    
) y
where max(y.rack-id) > 0;
```

You are missing a `GROUP BY new.bnumber` and also [HAVING](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx/) clause is use instead `WHERE` when you need to filter by aggregation.

---

```
DECLARE rowcount INT;

select count(*)
INTO rowcount
from Available inner join Rack 
    on 'Rack.rack-id' = 'Available.rack-id'
group by 'Available.rack-id'
ORDER BY 'rack-id'
LIMIT 1;


insert into Available ('bnumber','rack-id')
SELECT new.bnumber, rowcount
```

Comment: I added and changed what you suggested but it is not inserting into the table "Available" any ideas?

Comment: When I try to do 'insert into Available ('bnumber','rack-id')' it says "(" is not in a valid position for this server version?

Comment: I thought when the trigger is started new.bnumber would point to the bnumber from the inserted row? Am I wrong about this? If so how do I point to the new bnumber? Also, thanks for the help I do not know how to use triggers very well.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Can you try this?

Comment: it first threw "(" is not in a valid position for this server  after the insert into and when I deleted that part it then threw 1054: Unknown column 'rowcoun' in 'field list'